# How to set firewall's log in debian?

Tags: centos, debian, firewall, firewalld

I am familiar with debian,so i want to build my vps server with debian instead of centos.
There are log file `/var/log/firewalld` both in centos and debian.
In order to activate log function for firewall,it is simple to add below line into `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld` in centos

```
FIREWALLD_ARGS=--debug=10
```

and restart the service with `sudo systemctl restart firewalld`.

I found that there is no directory `/etc/sysconfig` ,shall i create directory and file in my debian?

```
mkdir  /etc/sysconfig
touch   /etc/sysconfig/firewalld
```

And do as in centos,it is the standard way to set firewalld'log in debian?

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/sysconfig/` is a configuration file directory you could find in Red Hat based distributions like [RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Network_Configuration_Using_sysconfig_Files.html) and [older Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-sysconfig.html), but not in Debian based distributions. Do not create the directory; nothing will read your configuration from there! The same has also been said in the Firewalld documentation for [HowTo: Debud firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/debug-firewalld.html):

> **The sysconfig file**
>
> This file exists in Fedora and RHEL based distributions, but may not
>   in others.
>
> ```
> # firewalld command line args
> # possible values: --debug 
> FIREWALLD_ARGS=
> ```
>
> To enable the debugging mode, add `--debug[=<level>]` to `FIREWALLD_ARGS`. For a list of the
>   supported debug levels, please have a look further down.

The "further down" has two options:

1. **The firewalld systemd service file**, 
   having the command line arguments in the line beginning with

   ```
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld
   ```

   In Debian, the path might be `/etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service`.
2. **Start in terminal** 
   as root with `# firewalld --nofork --debug=10`.

   > With the `--nofork` option the daemon is not doing a fork and stays in the foreground.